# Как реализовать отклик на нажатие ячейки в таблице

Tags: javascript

Есть таблица с тестовыми вопросами ( по медицине ). При  нажатие в ней на ячейку со знаком '?' в столбце вопросы должен появиться ответ.

[image: это результат html]

Вот мой код на JS. Что я сделал неправильно?
[image: это результат html]

```
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <table>
                <thead>
                    <tr>
                        <th>ID</th>
                        <th>ВОПРОСЫ</th>
                        <th>вата</th>
                        <th>питта</th>
                        <th>капха</th>
                        <th>ответы</th>
                    </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody>
                    <tr>
                        <th>1</th>
                        <td>телосложения</td>
                        <td class="selectVata">здоровый человек</td>
                        <td class="selectPitta">нормальный телосложения</td>
                        <td class="selectKapxa">худой человек</td>
                        <td class="out">?</td>  
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <th>2</th>
                        <td>глаза</td>
                        <td class="selectVata">карие глаза</td>
                        <td class="selectPitta">обычные глаза</td>
                        <td class="selectKapxa">синие глаза</td>
                        <td class="out">?</td>  
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <th>3</th>
                        <td>рост</td>
                        <td class="selectVata">длинный</td>
                        <td class="selectPitta">средние</td>
                        <td class="selectKapxa">короткий</td>
                        <td class="out">?</td>
                    </tr>
                </tbody>
            </table>
        </div>
    </div>

/***********JS**************/
let showAnswer = document.querySelectorAll('.out');
for( let out = 0; out < showAnswer.length; out++ ){
    // showAnswer[out].innerHTML = "VATA";
}


let selectVatalar = document.querySelectorAll('.selectVata');
let selectPittalar = document.querySelectorAll('.selectPitta');
let selectKapxalar = document.querySelectorAll('.selectKapxa');

for (let i = 0; i < selectVatalar.length; i++) { 
    let res = selectVatalar[i].onclick = selectValueVata; 
}
function selectValueVata(){
    showAnswer.innerHTML = "VATA";
}

for (let i = 0; i < selectPittalar.length; i++) { 
    selectPittalar[i].onclick = selectValuePitta; 
}
function selectValuePitta(){
    showAnswer.innerHTML = "PITTA";
}

for (let i = 0; i < selectKapxalar.length; i++) { 
    selectKapxalar[i].onclick = selectValueKapxa; 
}
function selectValueKapxa(){
    showAnswer.innerHTML = "KAPXA";
}
```

Comment: Исходные данные вы откуда берете?

Comment: неоткуда делаю сайт с направления  ayurveda

Comment: ну да можно главное там должно отображаться ответ

Comment: зарание благодарю что обратили внимание

Comment: https://codepen.io/muhtoryusufjanov/pen/gNYjGX

Comment: тут добавить код уже поздна да я думаю :(  но я отправил на codopen видели?

Comment: Ваш текст я подправил, но картинку с таблицей Вам придется вставить самому.

Comment: @Александр Муксимовя Thanks :) я новичок все же так научить ( знал что неправильно описал суть )

Comment: @ Рустам Гимранов  да если возможно

Answer (score 1):

При клике на `td` у многих браузеров есть стандартное поведение, которое нужно отменить. 
В начале функций `selectValueVata(e)`, `selectValuePitta(e)`, `selectValueKapxa(e)` нужно добавить

```
    if (e.stopPropagation) e.stopPropagation();
```

При присвоении ответа `showAnswer` является массивом, необходимо обращаться к нему включая индекс, например: `showAnswer[1].innerHTML = "VATA";`

В остальном ваш код работает.

Comment: спасибо всем кто обратил внимание и поправил меня Thanks:)